# How to extend the Context2d of a canvas?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

I want to extend Context2d in order to create a specific method that can be invoked by `context.myMethod();`

Using this class:

```
class MyContext extends Context2d {
    public myMethod();
}
```

BUT I'm creating the canvas by `Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();` and thus I would get the Context2d by `canvas.getContext2d();`

How can I now force the latest method to return `MyContext` class which extends the `Context2d`, as there is no `setContext2d`() on a canvas element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context2d` is a `JavaScriptObject` so all you need is to cast it to `MyContext` and/or use the `cast()` method:

```
MyContext ctx = canvas.getContext2d().cast();
```